# Проблема с псевдоклассом IE

Tags: css3, jquery, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

Всем доброго вечера.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
есть скрытый блок с `display:none`. В определенный момент я ему делаю `display:block`, и элементам внутри него при наведении на них мышки нужно менять фон. Реализовал это с помощью псевдокласса :`hover`. Все бы хорошо, но корректно работает это везде, кроме IE. В ослике же смена фона срабатывает через раз или вообще по клику...
Собственно вопрос, как с этим бороться?

Comment: Имхо либо вешать onmouseover-onmouseout, либо в качестве контейнера юзать тег `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запихнуть "div" в "a". `hover` для ссылок работает везде.

```
 <a href="" class="qwerty"><div> что-то </div></a>

.qwerty:hover div{
    background: #999;
}
```

Comment: не нужно так делать. Это не валидно. Лучше в css прописать:

display: block;

Comment: Или div заменить span'ом.

Answer (score 0):

Это нарушает семантику верстки.смотря с каким ие и каким методом пытаетесь бороться.если принципиальна поддержка 0.4%-го ие6,то только скриптами,либо почитайте про другой метод вот тут www.umade.ru/log/2004/07/css-hover-any-element/.если ие7-8 достаточно правильно doctype задать.а вообще метод jQuery hover() работает во всех браузерах.надо всего лишь добавить класс наведения к элементу,а после отвода мыши-удалить этот класс.

Comment: По-моему версткой уже давно правит госпожа Анархия и `<a><div>` - не повод к разочарованию. Правильно надо было делать лет 15 назад - ссылать на Чукотку тех, кто версткает как <s>ч</s>удак. Это так, замечание к "семантике")

Comment: интересно,как версткой может править анархия,если xhtml как раз таки и породил эту семантику?все элементы должны использоваться исходя из их назначения.